# Animation fill mode "forwards" in THREE.js

Tags: animation, three.js

My animation is working, but when finishes, back to original.
As I do to maintain the final state after the termination?
like "animation-fill-mode: forwards" in Css

```
this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.box);
this.animation = this.mixer.clipAction(this.box.geometry.animations[0]);
this.animation.setDuration(1.5);
this.animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce, 1);

this.mixer.addEventListener( 'finished', function() {
    this.animation.stop();
    // HOW animation-fill-mode: forwards ?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AnimationAction.clampWhenFinished](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.clampWhenFinished) to cause the animation to pause on the last frame once it has completed.

```
this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.box);
this.animation = this.mixer.clipAction(this.box.geometry.animations[0]);
this.animation.setDuration(1.5);
this.animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce, 1);
this.animation.clampWhenFinished = true;
```

Hope that helps!